# How to pass {% url 'category' %} in my category_list.html?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I have a detail view for categories and if i pass in the URL directly it works just fine. But if i want to pass it as a link in my template it gets an error. Here is my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse("home")
```

Here is my views:

```
class CategoryClassView(TemplateView):
    model = Category
    template_name = "categories.html"
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        cats = kwargs.get("cats")
        category_posts = Category.objects.filter(name=cats.replace('-', ' '))
        context = {'cats':cats.replace('-', ' ').title(), 'category_posts':category_posts}
        return context
```

Here is my URLS:

```
path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryClassView.as_view(), name='category')
```

Here is my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for category in category_list %}
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <span class="font-weight-bold"><a href="">{{ category.name}}</a></span> &middot;
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Could you write a more detailed explanation for your answer? Why is just passing  {% url 'category' %} is not working? A link to a list of useful materials would be also acceptable for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing this way, since you are having parameters in the url:

```
 {% url 'category' cats=category.name %}
```

Also you can use as:

```
{% url 'category' %}?cats={{ category.name }}
```

Comment: You have to change `path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryClassView.as_view(), name='category')` to `path('category/', CategoryClassView.as_view(), name='category')`. Nonetheless, passing a CharField to an url is a bad idea. I would suggest to use the `primary key` or to create an extra `SlugField` for that case.